# Filter with Username in Win32_Process WQL Query

Tags: vb.net, process, wmi-query, win32-process, wql

I want to ask any way can direct filter username in win32_Process WQL Query? If use looping with use GetOwner method is use much time to wait if too many user open same exe.

currently the query is Select * from win32_Process where name = 'example.exe'

Comment: This is a total guess so I'll post it as a comment rather than an answer. Can you do something like `WHERE GetOwner().User = 'user name here'` in the query?

Comment: @John, thanks for suggestion, but I tested with ("Select * from win32_Process where name = 'example.exe' And GetOwner().User = " & Environment.UserName) is not worked.

Comment: I don't suppose that specifically would work, because the user name would be a string and you'd need to wrap strings in single quotes. Does it work if you add the single quotes? Maybe try testing with a hard-coded value to begin with.

Comment: @John, also cannot. It show error Invalid Query